# Laravel-excel import custom heading

Tags: excel, laravel, formatting, row, laravel-excel

I'm using laravel-excel to import an excel file in my laravel project.  I use heading row to get the data by the heading. But it's only work if the heading is in a one row. What if the heading was like this picture? the heading isn't in one row.  How to get the data by the heading?

```
3rd row (no, year, sn code)
4th row (coo,start,finish,page)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `headingRow` as follow:

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new User([
            'name'  => $row['name'],
            'email' => $row['email'],
        ]);
    }
    
    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 2; //this should be the row number of heading row
    }
}
```

You can find here the details: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/heading-row.html#heading-row-on-different-row

Comment: what I mean by different heading row is that the row of (no, year, sn_code) is the 3rd row while (coo,start,finish,page) is the 4rth row. I think I should specified the return value for 2 different heading row (which idk how is it). This is not the right solution for different heading row

Comment: 1st increase the header row, could be it in in header 3-6, you can check by doing dd($result).

Next, you need to get data as:

$row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row['coo], $row['start'], ..... if there is no name, it will use index

Comment: If you could share the file I could give you the exact header number and also how to get the data.

Comment: hmm if that so, then instead of getting data as $row['year'], I will could only get data as $row[1] ?

so it would be better if I set the return header row as 5, so I could get every data as an index?

Comment: Yes, you could do that as well.